Can I connect sink disposal to drain pump?
I have a drain pipe under the sink that is too high for the new disposal.
Instead of paying thousands to move the pipe down (horizontal pipe + condo = $$$), can I just buy one those drain pumps on Amazon and connect it to the garbage disposal under the kitchen sink?
Something like this: https://a.co/d/0lUIf50
Picture of garbage disposal below.


You should be able to use a macerating pump of the type used for basement toilets. That's going to be a lot more expensive than the cheap clean-water pumps, though.

Do you really need a disposal?

No.
Those pumps require a vent connection which you do not have, so you're back to cutting holes in the wall to connect to a drain vent.
So you may as well just get the drain moved.
